# Refresh JTable data in Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have added text field and jTable in same frame. After getting value from the text field on jButton1 click, I am inserting the value in database and the same data is getting displayed in jTable . But the problem is my table is not getting updated itself after adding data . I have to evrytime execute the program to get table update . I have tried `Frame.invalidate, Frame.validate, Frame.repaint , tbale.repaint` but nothing worked out , where am I going wrong Thank you in advance..!

```
public class mainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

static JTable table;
static Connection connection;
static Statement statement;
static JTable jTable1;
static int count;
static String r;

/**
 * Creates new form mainFrame
 */
public mainFrame() {
    super();

    initComponents();
    setLocation(500, 180);
    try {
        //----------database
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = null;
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:excel.db");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testing (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , namexcel string)");

        //--------
        final String queryCheck = "SELECT count(*) from testing";
        final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
        // ps.setString(1, name);
        final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            count = resultSet.getInt(1);
            System.out.println(count);

        }

        String read = "select * from testing";
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(read);
        Object[][] data = new Object[count][2];
        int i = 0;
        while (rs.next()) {

            for (int c = 0; c < 1; c++) {
                data[i][c] = rs.getString("namexcel");

            }
            i++;

        }

        String[] headers = {"Name"};

        table = new JTable(data, headers);

        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(table);

        //     pack();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

//.....
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try {
        String link = jTextField1.getText();
        System.out.println("" + link + "");
        jTextField1.setText("");
        File f = new File("" + link + "");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File Doesnt Exist....!!");

        } else {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(f);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            String name = workbook.getSheetName(0);
            System.out.println(name);
            final String queryCheck = "SELECT count(*) from testing WHERE namexcel = ?";
            final PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(queryCheck);
            ps.setString(1, name);
            final ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                final int count = resultSet.getInt(1);
                if (count == 0) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "thank you");                        
                    statement.executeUpdate("insert into testing (namexcel) values('" + name + "')");
                mainFrame frame = new mainFrame();
                frame.invalidate();
                frame.validate();

                table.revalidate();

                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name Already exist please select diffrent name of excel");
                }
            }

        }

    } catch (Exception r) {

    }
}                                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    } 
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new mainFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
public static javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
```

}

following is the inicomponent method

```
 private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

    jButton1.setText("Add");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Add Excel Sheet Link");

    jTextField1.setText("");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(26, 26, 26)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addContainerGap())))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(20, 20, 20)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 13, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 350, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 394, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(20, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't do `table = new JTable(data, headers);` in your constructor. You are derefrencing the initial table you drag and dropped. Sure `jScrollPane2.setViewportView(table);` might have fixed it (by set the viewport to the new table) but this is unnecessary, and smells of future problems if you don't understand what's going on.
2. Instead work with the table's model to update. So instead of the `table = new JTable`, do

   ```
   DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
   table.setModel(model);
   ```

   That's it.
3. To update the table, just update the model, upon successful update in the database.

   ```
   if (successfulInsert) {
       DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
       Object[] row = .... // get the data for the row
       model.addRow(row);
   }
   ```

See more at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Creating a TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) and [DefaultTableModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Comment: Instead of "table = new JTable(data, headers)" I wrote "DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
table.setModel(model)" in constructor , but after executing table is not getting displayed .

Comment: I think the table you original table you drag and dropped is `jtable1`, no? In that case, use `jtable1`, instead of `table`. Look inside the `initComponents` method to make sure. There should be a `+` in the source code that will allow you to expand it

Comment: Yes I tried with DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers); jTable1.setModel(model); . Still table not getting displayed

Comment: Did you get rid of `jScrollPane2.setViewportView(table);`?

Comment: Yes I tried both the ways adding and removing jScrollPane2.setViewportView(table); but did'nt worked

Comment: Is `jtable1` the table that you added to the frame?

Comment: I checked initComponents but there is not jtable1 as such . I am sorry it was declared by myself in class, and I added table and not jtable1 .

Comment: I honestly don't think that `table` is even the table that you drag and dropped. Netbeans would _not_ make the field `static`. Did you drag and drop a table onto the frame or not?

Comment: Show your initComponents method

Comment: You never even dragged a table onto the frame. That's what I was asking. Drag a table onto the frame, and just use _that_ table.

Comment: But the rows and columns are going to be dynamic according to the database column count . So can I customize the table accordingly if I drag and drop the table..?

Comment: It doesn't matter, you are change the model in your constructor. The model is what is used to display the data. The initial data in the table doesn't matter. If you are going to use drag and drop, then it's best to just do it will all your components, instead of trying to add them by hand

Comment: thank you so much it worked now table is getting displayed, I am also using DefaultTableModel. Thank you for giving your time..!